# Microsoft onedrive files and folders access using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We are trying to download/access files from Microsoft OneDrive using MVC c#. We want to know the proper steps to download the file using c#. We searched many sites but there is only get and put links. Anyone have sample coding to download/access files from Microsoft one drive using asp.net

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553115/how-to-download-files-from-onedrive check this link it might be help you out